# Submit object contained within DropDownList selected value

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm stuck with this ASP.NET MVC 5 issue. I have implemented a razor view which contains a DropDownList control that is populated with objects set as values using javascript. This is the function that achieves such task:

```js
    function populateFilings(keyValueArray) {   
    
        var dropDown = document.getElementById('myDropDown');
    
        keyValueArray.forEach(function (item) {
            dropDown.options.add(new Option(item.Key, JSON.stringify(item.Value)));
        });
    }
```

The DropDownList is as follows (nothing really special here):

```
@Html.DropDownList("myDropDown", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The created select options have this appearance:

```html
<option value="{"FileName":"20220511T171503750.zip","FilingID":60,"BatchID":41,"FormTypeID":2,"SnapshotID":12}">Option 1</option>
```

And once the form is submitted, the following Controller method is executed:

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel model)
        {
            //not relevant code here
        }
```

The view model implementation is quite simple as well:

```cs
namespace ViewModels
{
    public class IndexViewModel
    {
        //Many not relevant properties

        public FilingBatch myDropDown { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And finally, the class that should contain the data placed in the DropDownList is implemented as follows:

```cs
    public class FilingBatch
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public int FilingID { get; set; }
        public int BatchID { get; set; }
        public int FormTypeID { get; set; }
        public int SnapshotID { get; set; }
    }
```

But the "myDropDown" property within the ViewModel is always null rather than containing an object populated with the values contained within the DropDownList. How can I fix this? What am I missing?

### EDIT

I have just tried @OkanKaradag suggestion but the model property keeps being null. For the sake of completeness, my initial form code is as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "myForm", encType = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    @*All fields code here*@    
}
```

I tried not only with both encType = "multipart/form-data" but also "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", and the result is exactly the same: model.myDropDown = null. The request payload has the following appearance:

```
myDropDown.FileName: 20220511T171503750.zip
myDropDown.FilingID: 60
myDropDown.BatchID: 41
myDropDown.FormTypeID: 2
myDropDown.SnapshotID: 12
```

Comment: `<option value="{"FileName` so the json isn't being escaped??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, post data should be like :

```
Name : "Foo", 
Address.City : "NYC",
Adress.Line1 : "Line1"
```

if it is `application/json`, should be:

```
{
  Name : "Foo",
  Address : {
     City: "NYC",
     Line1 : "Line1"
   }
}
```

### **Solution**:

In this case, content-type is form. formdata  should be modify before form submit. this could do with `'formdata'` event.

```
formElemet.addEventListener("formdata",(e) => {
     var dropdown = document.getElementById("myDropDown");
     const formData = e.formData;
     formData.delete('myDropDown');
     Object.entries(JSON.parse(dropdown.value))
                 .map((item) => 
                     formData.append(`myDropDown.${item[0]}`,item[1]));
})
```

edit : As OP mentioned myDropdown was deleted because it was already full

Comment: Tried your solution but something seems to be still missing. Please, have a look at the edited part of my question (couldn't place it here as it was too long to be included as a comment).

Comment: I finally fixed it using your solution: basically it didn't work because the former "myDropDown" property still existed within the FormData object. Adding the line formData.delete('myDropDown'); prior to appending the new data did the trick. If you complete your code with it I'll mark it as solution.

Answer (score 0):

`SelectList` is a name/value (or better said as key/value perhaps) pair for each one. Important here is the "value" you have set.  You will want to set these values as strings.

You probably want these:

```
<option value="{"FileName":"20220511T171503750.zip","FilingID":60,"BatchID":41,"FormTypeID":2,"S`napshotID":12}">Option 1</option>
```

to appear like (note the single quotes)

```
<option value='{"FileName":"20220511T171503750.zip","FilingID":60,"BatchID":41,"FormTypeID":2,"SnapshotID":12}'>Option 1</option>
```

In your model then set those as a `string` type and not a `FilingBatch` type. Then in your post back method where you have  `//not relevant code here` you will want de-serialize that string into the `FilingBatch` type.

Try a strong type using a `DropDownListFor` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.myDropDown, 
        new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>()), 
        new { @class = "form-control" })
```

As an aside try to work the property name `myDropDown` and prefer model property names to be like `MyDropDown` in your `IndexViewModel` or a better name to illustrate purpose for example `SelectedFilingBatch`, `SerializedFilingBatch` or some such.

Example

```
public string SerializedFilingBatch { get; set; }
```

Partial example

```
 FilingBatch? filingBatch = 
                JsonSerializer.Deserialize<FilingBatch>(model.SerializedFilingBatch);
```